# Is it possible to set Google forms to grade different points for respondent depending which option did they chose in a test question?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is it possible to set Google forms to grade different points for respondent depending which option did they chose in a test question?

For example, if respondent chose option "a" in the question they will get 10 points, if they chose option "b" they get 20 points, if they chose "c" they get 30 points...

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation from your question, if you want to achieve your goal using Google Form, in this case, how about calculating the value when the form is submitted? You can do this using the OnSubmit trigger. But, if you want to achieve your goal in real-time, how about using the custom form instead of Google Form? If those were not the direction you expect, I apologize.